# How to test for RDF language tags in ShEx?

Tags: rdf, shex

I would like to test for language tags in a Shape Expression (ShEx).
When testing for a string I usually use the following shape  like to use

```
<example> {
   ex:label xsd:string ;
}
```

the following shape works for a set of language tags

```
<example> {
       ex:label [@nl @en] ;
    }
```

But can I test for language tags in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- ```
  <example> {
     ex:label  rdf:langString ;
  }
  ```
- ```
  <example> {
     ex:label  [ @~ ] ;
  }
  ```

See also:

- [Node Constraints](https://shex.io/shex-semantics/#node-constraints)
- [Example](http://rdfshape.herokuapp.com/validate?data=%40prefix%20%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%40prefix%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%40prefix%20foaf%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%20.%0A%0A%3Acarol%20%20schema%3Aname%20%20%22Carol%22%40en%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%20%20%20%22Carol%22%40en%20.%0A&dataFormat=turtle&schema=PREFIX%20%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%20%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0A%0A%3AUser%20IRI%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20schema%3Aname%20%20%20%5B%20%40%7E%20%5D%20%3B%0A%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20rdf%3AlangString%0A%7D&schemaFormat=ShExC&schemaEngine=ShEx&triggerMode=ShapeMap&schemaEmbedded=false&inference=NONE&activeDataTab=%23dataTextArea&activeSchemaTab=%23schemaTextArea&activeShapeMapTab=%23shapeMapTextArea&&shapeMap=%3Acarol%40%3AUser)